# Add rel and title attributes on menu items programmatically

Tags: drupal

I have a menu built this whay:

```
function hook_menu()
{
    $items['footer_callback'] = array(
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'access callback' => true,
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('tac_webforms_footer_form'),
        'menu_name' => 'footer-menu',
        'title' => 'Newsletter'
    );
}
```

Is there any way I can pass something like an `options` attribute to add `rel` and `title` html attributes to the created `<a>` tag ?

According to the [docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), I can pass that `options` key I was talking about, but that doesn't work.

**P.S.:** I would like to do it programmatically, perferably without the use of any modules,

Answer (score 0):

This will add title attributes to most links on theme level, depends with some modules though. Maybe you could the same with rel attribute.

```
/**
 * Add title attribute to any link that doesnt have a title already
 */
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_link(&$vars) {
    // If title set and not empty dont do anything
    if (isset($vars['options']['attributes']['title']) && !empty($vars['options']['attributes']['title'])) {
        return;
    }

    // Use the link text as the title
    $vars['options']['attributes']['title'] = strip_tags($vars['text']);
}
```

Comment: The menu links are not on the `$vars` array... Any other hook that could include them?